# How to sort array of objects based on object value?

Tags: java

I want to sort Vehicles array based on `seats`. I tried looking for solutions here, but whenever I pass to `compareTo` method a `Vehicle` object, I get error in all my other files with classes for e.g `The type Bike must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Object)`. Can someone help me with this code?

```java
public abstract class Vehicle implements Comparable {
    
    protected int seats;
    protected int wheels;
    protected int price;
    protected int weight;
    
     public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {
        return -1;
    }

 public static void main(String [] args) {
        Car Lamborghini = new Car(5,4,30000, 1500);
        Bike BMX = new Bike(1,2,300, 15);
        Vehicle Vehicles[] = new Vehicle[2];

        Vehicles[0] = Lamborgini;
        Vehicles[1] = Bmx;

        Arrays.sort(Vehicles);
        for(int i=0;i<Vehicles.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(Vehicles[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `The type Bike must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Object)` where is your implementation of `compareTo` from `Bike`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

Change your comparator method to

```
public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {
       return this.seats < o.seats ? -1 : this.seats > o.seats ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Now you can pass the `Vehicle` array to `Arrays.sort();`

I also have to apologize.  I am so used to working with primitive arrays I forgot that you can pass a comparator to `Arrays.sort` when using Object arrays.  So you could also do the following:

```
Arrays.sort(Vehicles, Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getSeats)).
```

or pass any other criteria via a comparator.  If you want to reverse the sort you can do.

```
Arrays.sort(Vehicles, Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getSeats, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

To reverse the order in  your current implementation, just change the inequality signs.

Comment: I have to use Arrays.sort unfortunately.

Comment: See my updated asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
public abstract class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle>
```

instead of

```
public abstract class Vehicle implements Comparable
```

or change

```
public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {
```

to

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
```

Also go through a bit of Generics to get better understanding.

Comment: "*or change `public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {` to `public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {`*" - I suspect you wanted to change the parameter in the 2nd method to `Object`? If so: I would highly advice against that approach and only recommend the first solution of properly typing the `Comparable`-interface.

Comment: cant agree more